# Binding an attribute to a validator for SpecFlow unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, validation, specflow

So, I'm working with an MVC app that my team is testing using SpecFlow.  I use an implementation of `[RequiredIf(prop, val)]` that is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx).

However, I found a 'slight' issue - while the validations work just fine on the webpage, they break in our unit tests!  Upon investigation, I found that the IsValid() method of the attribute is getting directly called in our unit tests...likely because the Attribute is not being bound to the Validator.

On that blog, I followed the setup steps to register the RequiredIf attribute with the validator.  However, for the purposes of certain Unit Tests, I need to find out where to bind the validation in the testing setup.

I've tried a few more-or-less logical options:

```
[Binding]
public class TestSteps
{
     // Every test has to call this helper to load up the controller...
     private void GoToHome()
     {
         // SNIP: Unimportant
         DataAnnotationsViewModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(..., ...);
     }
}
```

...As well as in the Test Suite file...

```
// See attribute for why I figured this may be a logical choice.
[BeforeScenario]
public void Setup()
{
    DataAnnotationsViewModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(..., ...);
}
```

...Yet, for some reason, neither location causes `RequiredIf()` to bind to its `RequiredIfValidator()`.

Question: For unit testing, where do I put the Attribute -> Validator binding such that my Unit Tests will correctly validate properties that are decorated if `RequiredIf()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I'm not familiar with MVC validation so this may or may not work.

However, I'd guess that if you were using NUnit alone you might want to do something like this

```
[FixtureSetup]
public void ....()
{
    DataAnnotationsViewModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(..., ...);
}
```

And at the moment you are actually adding your validations via the Bindings, which is a whole reflection hop away.

However if you look in the auto-generated xxxxx.feature.cs file you can see the class is actually defined as

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "1.8.1.0")]
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute()]
[NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute("xxxxx")]
public partial class xxxxxFeature
{
```

Obviously we can't edit this, but we can create another file that implements anything we like in the partial class.

In xxxxx.partial.cs

```
public partial class xxxxxFeature
{
     [FeatureSetup]
     ....
```

If nothing else you have a few more places to try. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  For now, I settled with adding more responsibility to my `RequiredIf.IsValid()` implementation to no longer require registration.  Thanks for thinking about an answer - even we couldn't come up with one :(